# Ansible set_fact type cast

Tags: ansible

I have encountered a problem and hope to get your help, thank you!

Example:

```
 - hosts: localhost
   tasks:
   - name: "set variable"
     set_fact:
       test1:
         a: 1
   - name: "assignment"
     set_fact:
       test2:
         a: "{{test1.a}}"
   - name: "print test2"
     debug:
       var: test2
```

Output is :

```
"test2"：{ "a": "1"}
```

What i expect is :

```
"test2"：{ "a": 1}
```

Comment: Why would you expect that output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: *Output is : "test2"：{ "a": "1"}*

A: This is correct. An output of [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/) is a string (it's a template engine). You declared `test1.a` as an integer (without quotes)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        test1:
          a: 1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ test1.a|type_debug }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: int
```

But, the evaluation of `"{{ test1.a }}"` resulted in a string

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        test2:
          a: "{{ test1.a }}"
    - debug:
        var: test2
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ test2.a|type_debug }}"
```

give

```yaml
  test2:
    a: '1'

  msg: str
```

---

There are more options on how to preserve types.

1. Use configuration option [DEFAULT_JINJA2_NATIVE](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-jinja2-native) (default: False).

> "*This option preserves variable types during template operations.*"

This will influence the whole playbook. For example

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_JINJA2_NATIVE=True ansible-playbook pb.yml
```

gives

```yaml
  test2:
    a: 1

  msg: int
```

2. Next option is a combination of the dictionaries. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        test2: "{{ test2|default({})|combine({'a': test1.a}) }}"
    - debug:
        var: test2
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ test2.a|type_debug }}"
```

give

```yaml
  test2:
    a: 1

  msg: int
```

---

Single (bare) variables behave differently and preserve the types. For example

```yaml
   - set_fact:
        v2: 1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ v2 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ v2|type_debug }}"

    - set_fact:
        v3: "{{ v2 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ v3 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ v3|type_debug }}"
```

give

```yaml
  msg: 1
  msg: int
  msg: 1
  msg: int
```

<sup>(I've used `yaml` callback plugin `"ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook pb.yml"`)</sup>

Comment: Great, this is exactly what i want, thank you very much!

Comment: It seems to be a [moving target](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/porting_guides/porting_guide_base_2.11.html#playbook). You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This is default behaviour. I am unsure why you would expect the value to display without quotes.

Perhaps you're thinking the value is converted to a string, but it is not.

```yaml
   - name: set variable
     set_fact:
       test1:
         a: 1

   - name: check if variable is integer
     assert:
       that:
         - test1.a | type_debug == "int"
         - test1.a is regex("^[0-9]+$")

   - name: assignment
     debug:
       var: "{{ test1.a }}"
```