# Ansible debug variable output has dash

Tags: ansible, regexp-replace

I am trying to run below code and able to get the SID which will be passed to the URL but not sure why it is adding dash when I try to get the SID value using below code. I need to pass just the value to the URL.

Its basically about how to convert the dictionary item to a string, not sure how to do :|

```yaml
- set_fact: 
    regexp1: '\"sid"\: \"([^"]+)'

- set_fact: 
    ssid: "{{ dict | selectattr('Details','contains',item) | to_nice_json | regex_search(regexp1,'\\1')}}"

- debug: msg="{{ssid}}"
```

Output

```yaml
msg:
  - 01234567899
```

`sid: 01234567899` is the line I have in my dict.

It is passing the SID enclosed in square brackets with single quotes.

```
https://abc.service-now.com/api/now/table/sc_task/['01234567899']
```

I am expecting to see

```
https://abc.service-now.com/api/now/table/sc_task/01234567899
```

Comment: With the details you have shown in the question, it looks like  `ssid` is a list. You can try `debug` with `ssid[0]` to confirm.

Comment: How silly I am :|  and Thank you, It saved my day. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, the output is a list with one element counted from zero (`0`), a single element array.

To get a better insight into the variable type you may use according [Managing data type - Discovering the data type](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-data-types) `type_debug`.

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ ssid }} of type {{ ssid | type_debug }}"
```

For further processing you may access the list element by position like `ssid[0]` or use an other [Templating (Jinja2)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html) filter like [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.join) to convert the list to string.

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible - Check variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61256690/6771046)
- [Ansible - Type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104814/6771046)
- [How to join a list of strings in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47247544/6771046)