# Ansible: How to extract first element from list?

Tags: ansible

I have below output

```yaml
msg: '  [(''N5K'', ''5548UPQ'')] '
```

I've tried the following

```yaml
" {{ platform_list[0] }} "
```

but it returns one character only and I want to extract 'N5K'.

Comment: It's not a valid [YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/) list.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, the output is not a list but a string.

To get a better insight into the variable type you may use according [Managing data type - Discovering the data type](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-data-types) `type_debug`.

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ platform_list }} of type {{ platform_list| type_debug }}"
```

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible - Check variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61256690/6771046)
- [Ansible - Type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104814/6771046)

**How to proceed further?**

To get a better understanding you may have a look into the following [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    LIST: ['N5K', '5548UPQ']

  tasks:

  - name: Show type
    debug:
      msg: "{{ LIST }} and of type {{ LIST | type_debug }}"

  - name: Show element
    debug:
      msg: "{{ LIST[0] }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show type] *********************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '[u''N5K'', u''5548UPQ''] and of type list'

TASK [Show element] ******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: N5K
```

You can then change the `vars` in example into a string

```yaml
  vars:

    STRING: "['N5K', '5548UPQ']"

  tasks:

  - name: Show type
    debug:
      msg: "{{ STRING }} and of type {{ STRING | type_debug }}"

  - name: Show element
    debug:
      msg: "{{ STRING[0] }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show type] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '[''N5K'', ''5548UPQ''] and of type AnsibleUnicode'

TASK [Show element] **************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '['
```

because of Python [Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing).